# When using VeraCrypt, which is preferable, the passphrase generated by Diceware or the key file?

Tags: encryption, passwords, disk-encryption, password-management, veracrypt

I have important files stored in a VeraCrypt container. The files in the container must never be seen.

In the unlikely event that they are seized by the secret police, which is stronger, the passphrase generated by Diceware or the key file?

The contents of this container are not opened very often. Therefore, I do not have the opportunity to enter passphrases on a daily basis, and it is difficult to remember them without writing them down.
On the other hand, the key file is somewhere on a computer I own. It may be possible to break the encryption by doing a brute force hit on the files on the computer I own.

Comment: I'm sure more data is lost to forgotten passwords than to the secret police. Here's a trick, which you can modify to suit. Make the password the names of the authors of three books, which you keep top left in your bookcase.

Comment: @Tetsujin And what happens when someone rearranges the books?

Comment: @DavidPostill - You see them every day. You know which books they are. You can eventually visualise them, you don't have to go check. You could do the same with three books with the same colour spines, plonked right in the middle at random. It's a mnemonic more than a true reference. It's a 'real' book cipher, one that no-one can guess… unless they know you use this specific method & where you placed them… or have the resources to set some TV-style detective, with nothing better to do in life, to crack the code… It bypasses the mundane.

Answer (score 0):

The keyfile must be stronger as the size can be between 64 to 1048576 bytes.
We humans cannot remember that long a password.

Your concern if the key file is found.

Why not do:

1. Type yourself some line of text only you will understand. Say "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
2. Type some reminder for the above only you understand so you need to run say a sha512sum for the last 5 words and append these to create the password.